# Content fit the screen after certain re-size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Under 1024 of width I'd like body of the page to fit the screen of a user without a scrollbar. Basically, I want to scale whole body so that it fits screen browser(without scrollbar) under 1024 width.
I tried something like this:

```
function resizeWindow() {
   $(window).off('scroll');

   windowWidth = $(window).width();
   console.log(windowWidth);
     if (windowWidth > 1024) 
     {
         console.log(">1024");
     }else if (windowWidth <= 1024) 
     {
       $('body').css('height', '100vh');
       $('body').css('width', '100vw')
     }
}

$(window).resize(resizeWindow);
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Setting the viewport meta usually is enough 
 check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Comment: Also you "can't" really change the `body, html`'s width. Add a wrapper element inside your `body`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media` query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  body, html {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
  }
}
```